# C# MVC Code first not returning all fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am new to MVC and i'm using code-first method with Web API 2. Here is my model:

ChildModel.cs

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class ChildModel
{
   //other fields definition here

   //relationship definition
   [DataMember]
   public int ParentModelID {get; set;}
   [DataMember]
   public virtual ParentModel ParentModel {get; set;}
}
```

then here is my controller action:

```
public IEnumerable<ChildModel> Get()
{
   return db.ChildModels.ToList();
}
```

So no problem in database generation. It creates the table. I can save and edit. There's just one problem, the Get controller action. When I access it from my frontend this is what the returned JSON looks like:

```
[
   {$id: 1, Field1: "", Field2: ""},
   {$ref: 3}
   ...
   {$id: 10, Field1: "", Field2: ""},
   {$ref: 12}
]
```

It goes alternate like that. The first JSON is complete then the next is just a $ref field. What could be causing this? Also I notice that when I remove the navigation property of the parent model inside the child model, everything seems to work fine except the parent model isn't eager loaded inside the child model's JSON.

Hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're not eager loading parent model anywhere, since there is no `Include` in your query. When you try to return your database objects directly to an API, that API will try to serialize them to Json or XML, making a full scan of your objects.

To solve your problem, you could do this:

```
public IEnumerable<ChildModel> Get()
{
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    try
    {
        return db.ChildModels.Include("ParentModel").ToList();
    }
    finally
    {
        db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

> I took care of disabling and re-enabling lazy load, since it seems you are sharing a `db` with dependency injection in your Controller's constructor.

---

What the serializer would normally do without `IsReference = true` is:

- Serialize Child Id 1
- Serialize Child `ParentModel` (accessing it would trigger lazy load)
- Serialize ParentModel (which was lazily loaded)
- Serialize ParentModel's collection of `ChildModel`
- Eventually Child Id 1 would be found
- Serialize Child Id 1 again

Infinite loop. By applying `IsReference = true` your avoid this, because once the serializer detects an object that was previously serialized, instead of serializing it again, it will fill with something like this:

```
$ref: 3
```

...meaning that object references another one of Id 3.

Considering your child with Id 3 has the same parent as Id 1, this is what would happen, then:

- Serialize Child Id 1
- Serialize Child `ParentModel` (accessing it would trigger lazy load)
- Serialize ParentModel (which was lazily loaded)
- Serialize ParentModel's collection of `ChildModel` (triggers lazy load)
- Collection of ChildModel is lazily loaded (containing two children, Id 1 and 3)
- Add a `ref` to child 1 (it was previously serialized)
- Serialize Child Id 3
- Finished Parent Model children serialization
- Finished Parent Model serialization
- Finished Child Id 1 serialization
- Add a `ref` to child 3 (it was previously serialized)
- Serialize Child Id 10
- ...keep serializing other objects

That's why I disabled lazy load and **eager loaded** parent model with `Include()`.

Now, this only happens because you are trying to return your database objects directly to an API. That's why people usually use **projection** to return DTO/ViewModel objects instead.

Comment: Turning off lazy load still doesn't work. I'm still getting the same output.

Comment: @Jed try removing `IsReference = true`, there is no need for it anymore, although it should work with it, as soon as you load each entity only one time (because as I said, the next times they will appear as a ref in your json). Try removing it and tell me if it works.

Comment: @Allison no it's still the same even after removing IsReference = true. I also deleted the database first just to be sure that it gets refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly EF uses Lazy Loading. 
Try add `.Include(c => c.ParentModel)` to your controller action before calling to list.

This should tell EF to resolve the references and extract the full object.